# BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException for React Native

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native, android-permissions

When I go to select an image from the image picker I get this error. I never got it until I started using permissions in my app. Here are my sdk versions:

```
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }


    dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
}

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:4.0.0-alpha1"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:4.0.0-alpha1"

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27+'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}
```

I read other questions to help me with this problem and found this java code for permissions:

```
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

ChoosePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(EditProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EditProfileActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        } else {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
       switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                  startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
                } else {
                    //do something like displaying a message that he didn`t allow the app to access gallery and you wont be able to let him select from gallery
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

I put it inside the class of my `mainactivity.java` file and got this error: `error: <identifier> expected
ChoosePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`. I am not sure if this could be the solution to fix the permissions error.

Stacktrace:

```
    07-22 17:59:03.978  8497  8497 D ViewRootImpl@39eadf9[UCropActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
07-22 17:59:03.992  8497  8497 E BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMMQY/IMG_20180722175858_942.jpg (No such file or directory)
07-22 17:59:03.996  8497  8497 W System.err: java.lang.Exception: Invalid image selected
```

Native Code:

```
    componentDidMount(){
async function requestCameraPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        'title': 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                   'so you can take awesome pictures.'
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the camera")
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied")
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Which of the three problems you've mentioned are you asking about? `FileNotFoundException`? `SecurityPermission`? `error: <identifier> expected`?

Comment: `BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMMQY/IMG_20180722175858_942.jpg (No such file or directory)` I guess. The `error identifier` is from what I thought would be the solution to that problem. @EJP

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid this can help you to take permission for read write in React native you don't need to go into android native that deep to edit mainActivity!.. I can see the permission taking and handling is the issue... try that and if works then ok else I will give  an example? in answers

Comment: @Rizwanatta I tried this and I still crash. Maybe I am not implementing it correctly?

Comment: please show the code where you are doing this! the react native camera permission

Comment: @Rizwanatta I updated my question with the code, also in my manifest I have the correct camera permissions.

Comment: ok what does the console command say? when permission is granted or not? if its on granted! then I will suggest first test your app on a small api  I mean lesser than api 23 based phones! just to see there isn't anything fishy in the code!  and if that's good and works then next you have to see run time permission demand! which will require native android code tweek

Comment: @Rizwanatta The console does that say anything. There is no output for some reason. I tested this many times and put the code everywhere. Still no result.

Comment: Can you show your onActivityResult code?

Comment: What do you mean by that? @Man

Comment: you are using startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY) so you must have overriden onActivityResult method. I'm asking for that?

Comment: @Man Oh I am not using that because it is not working for me (`error: <identifier> expected
ChoosePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`) and I am using the `react-native permissions` that @Rizwanatta suggested. Would I need to edit my mainactivity.java to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things 1. you need to add permission in manifest for external read storage then after you can able to use it and if you are using api above 23 then you have to use Easy permission.

To Write:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To Read:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Above 23:

```
 private String[] galleryPermissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
 Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

 if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, galleryPermissions)) {
        pickImageFromGallery();
    } else {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Access for storage",
                101, galleryPermissions);
    }
```

2. In Android 4.4 and up are about to remove them. And the uri you get has already no path.

You can still access the file content either through an InputStream (ContentResolver#openInputStream(Uri uri)) or through a file descriptor.

And that does also work on older android versions

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && null != data) {
    decodeUri(data.getData());
 }
  }

   public void decodeUri(Uri uri) {
   ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFD = null;
    try {
    parcelFD = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor imageSource = parcelFD.getFileDescriptor();

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(imageSource, null, o);

    // the new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(imageSource, null, o2);

    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle errors
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // handle errors
    } finally {
    if (parcelFD != null)
        try {
            parcelFD.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignored
        }
     }
           }
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you, before I try this code, do I have to import anything in the `MainActivity.java`? Or do I have to install Easy Permissions for React Native? @DishaMohite

Comment: no you don't need to implement anything to MainActivity.java and for React Native check this link https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions required permissions are there

Comment: I got this error in the `MainActivity.java`: `MainActivity.java:19: error: illegal start of type
 if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, galleryPermissions))` I put it inside the body class.

Comment: please check closing braces in  your code because generally error: illegal start of type comes when your closing brace is  misplaced

Comment: I found a code from Medium that works for me. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

See this site:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting
You might not have the camera permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Also see this:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid
The problem may be that you don't have React Native's camera permission.

Comment: Thank you, but I do have camera permissions in my xml. Plus when I go to the app it does asks and I allow it. But it crashes right after. @Divergence

Comment: @LaneyWilliams what is the exception thrown? Is it the same one?

Comment: this is the exception thrown: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media` when I use adb logcat

Comment: Can you edit your question with some code provided, steps to reproduce the problem, and where the error originates? (line) @LaneyWilliams

Comment: Also, this may seem strange, have you tried denying the permission? If it doesn't crash after that, it may be something in your code. Also check my edits. @LaneyWilliams

Comment: Sure thing. I did try deny the permission, but it just tells me in order to use the camera I must accept it. I remember one answer said that if I am getting such a warning it is because I have different versions of the same app. And I might have because I used `react-native-rename` to change the name of the app.

Comment: Try manually uninstalling the app and reinstalling. Can you attach the stacktrace that the logcat printed? Also, is the Camera required (critically important to your app) or is it an add-on feature? (For example, using the camera in an SMS messaging app.)

Comment: Ok I did reinstall it. I'll attach the stacktrace in the questions. And yes it is an add on feature for the image picker.